# Identify black dots on lemon

Tags: python, opencv, threshold

I'm trying to identify black dots on a lemon I've had several attempts. I have problem of differentiating black shadows with the actual black stains on the lemon.

I've tried to use `InRange` and converting the image to HSV with no success and honestly I'm quite lost and would appreciate some new ideas to identify the black stains.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("./data/lemon1big.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

plt.imshow(thresh)
```

Result:

[image: Original Image]

[image: Grayscale]

[image: Threshold]

These are the stains I want to detect - There are 12 stains I detected:

[image: Result]

Comment: What have you tried? The naive solution to this problem would be to define a stain as a dark patch surrounded by a light patch.

Comment: This question is a lemon.... LOL

Comment: @Denziloe Like I said, I tried using `inRange`, and `medianblur` the image to get rid of noise but I had no success - Some stains were simply unable to detect and were confused with the dots on the lemon

Comment: Maybe determine the size of the spot detected and if it's too small discard the detection...

Comment: That's not what you said the problem was in the question, so perhaps you should edit it. And if you're just looking for general approaches to this problem then you should say so.

Comment: You might try to negatize the image and detect white spots....

Comment: @AnyMoose I appreciate your good will to help but.. how do I do that? Can you show me an example? Thank you!

Comment: @Denziloe I definitely look for a better approach to detect the black stains. I edited the title. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reccommend to use adaptative threshold instead of otsu because the black background messes up the threshold calculation that otsu does, then you can obtain the black dots using connected components analysis and filtering by size, here the code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotImg(img):
    if len(img.shape) == 2:
        plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()
    else:
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        plt.show()

img = cv2.imread('lemon.png')
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
binary_img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                   cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 131, 15)
plotImg(binary_img)
_, _, boxes, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binary_img)
# first box is the background
boxes = boxes[1:]
filtered_boxes = []
for x,y,w,h,pixels in boxes:
    if pixels < 10000 and h < 200 and w < 200 and h > 10 and w > 10:
        filtered_boxes.append((x,y,w,h))

for x,y,w,h in filtered_boxes:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255),2)

plotImg(img)
```

[binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y6cn.png)

[image recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2tbo.png)

Comment: Thank you so so much! there is one dot which is missed out, on the top left corner of the lemon. have any idea how to find it? I thought of making another check of Black/White values. What do you think?

Comment: Play with the different parameters until you get the expected result